# Always have Jupyter notebook load with certain options / packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to ensure that jupyter notebook always starts with either:

1) Certain packages imported
and/or 
2  Certain options set

I don't want to have to type the same things everytime at the the top of each notebook I run - e.g. always using numpy or pandas.

Additionally, I always want to be able to see multiple output per cell.  I use the following code to let this work just fine, but I want this saved as some sort of template, that doesn't require manual effort from me to type each time.

Thanks!

```
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you find where the `startup` folder is located.

```
# on Jupyter notebook
import IPython
IPython.paths.get_ipython_dir()
```

On Windows, the response is `u'C:\\Users\\yourname\\.ipython'`, while on Linux  `~/.ipython`.

In that location, there are profile folders. At least, there is a `profile_default` on your computer. One `startup` folder exists in each profile folder.

You put a python script file in that folder (my case: `C:/Users/myname/.ipython/profile_default/startup`).

I name my script file `00-first.py`, and put this code in it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

When I start the Jupyter notebook server with the default profile, the startup script will be executed prior to opening a Jupyter notebook.

On a newly open Jupyter notebook, you can use numpy and pandas (as np, pd) without importing them first.

```
print(np.pi) #3.141592...
```

Comment: is there a way to have this printed into a cell at the top of the notebook as well so that if the notebook is shared the dependencies are apparent to the next user?

Comment: @shanlodh; Doing so is not enough to show all dependencies. Some are not apparent.