# Is it possible to run ipython with some packages already imported?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

Is it possible to run ipython with some packages already imported?
almost every time when I run `ipython` I do `import numpy as np`, is it possible to automate this process? i.e. just after I run `ipython` I want to be able to write something like `np.array([0,1])`. Is it possible?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737950/always-have-jupyter-notebook-load-with-certain-options-packages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Always have Jupyter notebook load with certain options / packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737950/always-have-jupyter-notebook-load-with-certain-options-packages)

Comment: The `--pylab` command line option is handy.  It imports `np` and `pylab` (matplotlib).  But check the `pylab` and `pylab_import_all` options in the config file. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html

Comment: I use an OS alias: `'ipython3 --pylab --nosep --term-title --InteractiveShellApp.pylab_import_all=False'`

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Mac add a script like `load_numpy.py` under `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/` directory and add the import statements you need to that script. Every time you run `ipython`, all the scripts in the startup directory will be executed first and so the imports will be there. in case of Ubuntu add the file to `~/.config/ipython/profile_default/startup/`

Comment: For me the folder is at ~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/  (Ubuntu 22.10)